How to set a Document ID in firebase based on the data of the submitted vue3 form
There is a code:
import { collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { requestGiftCard } from '@/firebase';
const name = ref();
const surname = ref();
const email = ref();
const number = ref();
const showAllItems = ref(false);


const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
        
        const formDataCollection = requestGiftCard;

       
        await addDoc(formDataCollection, {
            name: name.value,
            surname: surname.value,
            email: email.value,
            number: number.value,
            
        });

        name.value = '';
        surname.value = '';
        email.value = '';
        number.value = '';
        
        console.log('Form data sent successfully!');
        console.log(formDataCollection);
    } catch (error) {
        
        console.error('Error sending form data:', error);
    }
};

You need to make sure that when submitting the form, the Document ID in the firebase collection is the same as the first and last name that were entered in the form.
In fact, I don't even know if it is possible to implement such a thing, but if possible, I will be very grateful to someone who will write how to do it.
There was an attempt to implement it, but it was not successful:
const documentId = `${name.value}-${surname.value}`;

        // Отправьте данные в коллекцию с уникальным Document ID
        await addDoc(formDataCollection, {
            name: name.value,
            surname: surname.value,
            email: email.value,
            number: number.value,
            // Добавьте другие данные из формы по мере необходимости
        }, { id: documentId });


Using first and last name as a document ID is Firestore is a bad idea.  IDs need to be unique, and personal names are definitely not unique.

But when you do get a good unique ID, use setDoc instead of addDoc as shown in the documentation.
